# Show that T T is an unbounded, injective operator, that its inverse is bounded and that the range of T T is dense in L 2 (0,1) L2(0,1) .

Tags: vector-spaces

$\newcommand\N{\Bbb N} \newcommand\R{\Bbb R}$

Let $\{e_k|k\in\N\}$ and $\{f_k|k\in\N\}$ be two orthonormal bases of $L^2(0,1)$. Let $X=span\{e_k|k\in\N\}$, endowed with the $L^2$-norm. Hence $X$ consists of $finite$ linear combinations of the basis elements $e_k$. Consider the linear operator $T: X\to L^2(0,1)$, defined by $T_{e_k}=kf_k$, $k\in\N$. Show that $T$ is an unbounded, injective operator, that its inverse is bounded and that the range of $T$ is dense in $L^2(0,1)$.

I found that $T$ is unbounded because the operator norm is equal to $k$ for $k\in \N$.  I found that $T$ is injective because the kernel of $T$ consists of only the zero vector. But I am unsure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $T(X)=Y:=\textrm{span}\{f_k|k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $T^{-1}:Y\to L^2(0,1)$ is given by $T^{-1}(f_k)=\frac{1}{k}e_k$. I think you can take it from here to show that this map is bounded.

Comment: $T(X)=Y$ of course also establishes density of the image of $T$.